# Permanent changes to WildFly 10 configuration (standalone.xml)

Tags: configuration, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

How can I make these two Wildfly 10 configuration changes permanent?

- max-parameters="4000"
- <access-log />

If I write them to **standalone.xml** and restart Wildfly, they disappear.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
  <buffer-cache name="default"/>
  <server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" max-parameters="4000" />
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
      <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
      <access-log/>
      <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
      <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
    </host>
  </server>
...
```

Harri

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shutdown the server before you manually edit standalone.xml, or edit it using the command line console if you want to set it on the fly.

Comment: Or better yet don't edit the `standalone.xml` and use CLI or the web console. `/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/setting=access-log:add` and `/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=max-parameters, value=4000)`